# How to format ndjson files in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatter, ndjson

I am trying to format ndjson file in VS Code but it keeps coming up with the message that there is no ndjson file formatter installed. Any idea how to resolve this ? I can't seem to find any extension for formatting ndjson. Shouldn't it just use the default json formatter ?

Comment: if `ndjson` has the same structure as `json` then change the languageID of the editor to `json` and use the formatter